# Error message when Windows Powershell is opened

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11

I'm getting the following error message upon launching Windows PowerShell.
Any solution for this error ?

---

failed to create process.

Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Users\Username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:96

- ... onda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:PSObject) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
    keExpressionCommand

---

Comment: Please paste you profile file i.e profile.ps1

Comment: Are you laughing 32 or 64 bit? To run a script or the IDE?

Comment: There are [multiple profile files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/), so in addition to the one in the error message, be sure to check out the others too.

Comment: There exists a profile.ps1 file already in the folder.

Comment: @user13553961 Yeah, we're asking what exact code it contains. It looks like you followed a guide/tutorial to set up a virtual environment for conda, but hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the whole thing

Comment: There is some more error description when Anaconda prompt is launched with run as administrator.
failed to create process.
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Users\Username\anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:101 char:36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed... contd.

Comment: I haven't created any virtual env in conda recently. I don't remember since when this issue exists. But, I can tell you that my OS got upgraded to Windows 11 a few days ago. I'm not sure if this is something related to upgrade.

Comment: What version of conda do you have instaled? Apparently there is an issue with version [4.6.14](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8598). Yu could try downgrading to 4.6.12 or try upgrading to version 4.7

Comment: Even i'm not able to check conda version in anaconda prompt.
Basically, cmd, powershell, anaconda prompt all have only one message "failed to create process." for any command given.